# Is there a way to read a cell's coordinates in JS for google sheets? or a way to remotely move the "current cell"

Tags: javascript, excel, google-sheets

I would like to basically read cell by cell as you would do in Excel using VBA but I can't manage to read the coordinates of the current cell, is there a way to do that? I'll attach what I have below.

````
    var total= 0, count = 0;
    //var Sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
    //var Cell = Sheet.getCurrentCell();
    var ess = [];
    ess[0] = 1;//original cell
    ess[1] = 0;//next column
    ess[2] = 2;//next column
    ess[3] = 0;//next column
    ess[4] = 3;//next column
    ess[5] = 1;//next column
    ess[6] = 9;//next column

    for( x in ess ){

        if(ess[x] > 0){
            total += ess[x];
            count++;
        }

    }
    var avg = total / count;
    console.log(avg);
    //console.log(Cell);
    //SpreadsheetApp.setCurrentCell(avg)

}```
````

Comment: what is the larger purpose of the code?

Comment: I want to make an adjustable average of a certain metric but only take into account the non-zero entries, and since this process needs to be done about 10 times per sheet I would love to automate it by just choosing a starting cell.

Comment: is there a reason scripting is necessary instead of just AVERAGEIF(A2:G2,">0")?

Comment: That could work too I guess, but I would still love to still fully understand reading and writing in cells. Although, I would also need a "failsafe" so if all values are 0 I get a 0 back instead of just an error.

Comment: Also, I just realized that Average.if only works with a continuous range of cells, since you can't segment them with ";"

Comment: You can segment them with AVERAGEIFS() as long as there is a pattern or something in the header row that can be used to tell you which columns you're interested in.  Also, IFERROR(... , 0) is used for the other comment you had.

Comment: the IFERROR helped a lot but I still can't make the AVERAGEIFS work, as of right now they are in the same column and spaced evenly by 8 cells.  

=(M6+M14+M22+M30)/4

Comment: This empty sheet was specifically created for this forum question.  Please share some sample data there so it's easier for folks to help.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xuFct0kM-GcmajXGM5vNAsSBpPCHOfc1AEjzGAeFTiU/edit

Comment: Great, I already added a simplified version on my sheet but cut off all the clutter.

Comment: I put this formula in cell C25:
=AVERAGEIFS(10:10,9:9,"Metric B")

Comment: I tried to apply it to my own sheet but I guess I cut off too much of the other stuff and realized I'll need to have them in a column but there is some text in between and I can't easily move it somewhere else. I'll recreate in the sheet but by any chance do you know how could I have something similar to "ISNUMBER" in a AVERAGEIFS format?